# portlet unavailable when adding servlet-api.jar to my project

Tags: java, servlets, websphere, portlet, ibm-rad

i inherited a legacy application deployed on websphere. part of my task is to create a servlet. 
however when after checking out the project from SVN and creating my servlet, i get a **Portlet Unavailable** error.

When i removed the servlet-api.jar, the portlet is working properly again. however, my servlet won't run anymore as the project does not have the servlet jar file. naturally, all references to the said jar file now generates **cannot be resolved** errors.

i then checked existing servlets created by the previous programmer and found that they do not have the above mentioned errors. the only difference i can see is that the IDE, IBM RAD, has **yellow arrows** besides these lines of code:

[image: Working Servlet]

while mine has these:

[image]

have you ever encountered this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to deploy your own servlet jar, that should be provided by the container.you should only need that during compilation.

Comment: There is no such class javax.servlet.http.getServletContext

Comment: @DaveNewton so having errors in the IDE regarding missing jar files is fine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project

Comment: @user571099 It won't compile then; see Balus' answer. What I *said* was that you shouldn't*deploy* your own servlet jars.